# Use Jupyter notebooks as function calls

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

How to invoke a `*.ipynb` file as if it was a generic python function accepting an input and producing an output?

For example, `graph_parser.ipynb` is a Jupyter notebook, it needs as input some file path (e.g. `.\location\big_graph.txt`) and produces as output some pyhton object.
Immagine a generic python script, for example running on a web-server, calling the notebook with `notebook_result = run_notebook("local/path/to/graph_parser.ipynb", ".\location\big_graph.txt")` and getting the pyhton object produced by the notebook assigned to `notebook_result`.

How would you go about achieving this? How to invoke a `*.ipynb` file, passing in some arguments and getting the output of the computation out?
I know the tool nbconvert provides a [python API to execute a `*.ipynb file` programmatically](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute_api.html#executing-notebooks-using-the-python-api-interface) so I suppose one way would be to hardcode in the `*.ipynb` file an input and an output folder but I am looking for a more flexible apporach.

#### Motivation

I would like to use Jupyter Notebooks as function calls because they offer a fast way of visualising and improving processing steps in complex pipelines. In a project I was involve we ended duplicating the code of a notebook for converting an edge list into a complex python object. We needed the notenook because it was useful for experimenting but we also needed a standalone python function to parse graphs server-side.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be seeking [Papermill](https://github.com/nteract/papermill#execute-via-the-python-api). It has a lot of ways to run and is flexible. You can program inside the notebook you'll call to make the Python object you want, such as a pickled set of data, etc.. See [this article with a similar title as your post](https://towardsdatascience.com/jupyter-notebook-as-a-function-create-reusable-notebooks-with-papermill-8f9bea5b9727).

Related to this you could get most of the way using jupytext to run the notebook code. Jupytext let's you convert to python if you want and then you could make it ipython by changing the extension to `.ipy` if you have magic. It can also execute notebooks and depending on how you do things, you can inject things into them before you run them or make templates.

Getting more complex than papermill, there's [ploomber](https://github.com/ploomber/ploomber).